# Class member function unable to access a private struct node of the same class?

Tags: c++, class, declaration, public-method

I was working on a homework assignment and I stumbled upon a roadblock

I created a linked list class that looks something like this

```
List.h
class List{
   struct Node{
       string data
       etc...
   }

   public:
       Node* lastNode(Node* root);
```

```
  List.cpp

  #include "List.h"

  List::Node* lastNode(Node* root){
      while(root && root->next){
          root = root->next;
      }
      return root;
  }
```

When I try to run the code, it says "struct List::Node is private" within this context (starting with the function header for lastNode in List.cpp)

I'm not understand what's causing this. I know that private fields can only be accessed by member functions of the same class, but isn't lastNode a member function?

Comment: In the .cpp file, `lastNode` should be `List::lastNode`.

Comment: That's a **very common** typo. It should be your first suspect when the compiler complains about access rights.

Answer (score 0):

```
List::Node* lastNode(Node* root) { ... }
```

defines a *global* function named `lastNode` returning a `List::Node*`. You wanted to define this as a *member* function of `List`. To do this, you simply qualify the name `lastNode` with `List::`.

```
List::Node *List::lastNode(Node *root) { ... } // * placement is more idiomatic this way
```

The second `List::`, on the function name, declares that this function "belong"s to `List`, so the second `Node`, which comes after it, does not need to be qualified by `List::` again. The return type, since it comes before the `List::` on the last node, is still interpreted in global scope, and so you need to qualify it. I don't think there's any good reason for this except historical inertia, a holdover from when compilers were dumb enough to get confused by this. You can also place the return type after the qualified function name, where you can leave off the qualifier:

```
auto List::lastNode(Node *root) -> Node* { ... }
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:14,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:14,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:14,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:14),source:'%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%0Aclass+List+%7B%0A++++struct+Node+%7B%0A++++++++std::string+data%3B%0A++++++++Node+*next%3B%0A++++%7D+*self%3B%0A++++public:%0A++++Node*+lastNode(Node+*root)%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aauto+List::lastNode(Node+*root)+-%3E+Node*+%7B+%0A++++return+root%3B+//+TODO%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang900,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+9.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)